# Linked List Loop detection

Tags: c++

Taken the following Exercise from Cracking the coding interview:

```
Given a linked list which might contain a loop, implement an algorithm that
returns the node at the beginning of the loop (if one exists).

EXAMPLE

Input:  A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> C [the same C as earlier]

Output: C
```

My Solution here was to store each node in a unordered_set. If we insert a node and it already exists it must be the begin of the loop.

Here my code:

LinkedList.h - Impelments a very primitive LinkedList with some operations. I know it has flaws (like not cleaning the memory. But not the concern of this question).

MySolution.cpp - Function `findBeginning` is the solution. Rest is some helper code to test with a looped list and a non looped list.

**LinkedList.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Node{
    T val;
    Node *next;

    ~Node() {
        std::cout << "destroyed: " << val << '\n';
    }
};

template<typename T>
Node<T>* makeNode(T value)
{
    return new Node<T>{value, nullptr};
}


Node<char>* makeLinkedList(const std::string& values)
{
    Node<char>* head = nullptr;
    Node<char>* curr = nullptr;

    for(const auto& value : values) {
        auto newNode = makeNode(value);

        if(head == nullptr) {
            head = newNode;
            curr = head;
        }
        else {
            curr->next = newNode;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}


template<typename T>
void printLinkedList(Node<T> * head)
{
    auto curr = head;
    while(curr != nullptr) {
        std::cout << curr->val << " -> ";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    std::cout<< "nullptr" << "\n";
}
```

**MySolution.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <unordered_set>

/*
Store each node in a unordered_set. If Item already exsists in unordered set
it must be the beginning of the loop
*/
template<typename T>
Node<T>* findBeginning(Node<T>* head)
{
    if(head == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::unordered_set<Node<T>*> table;

    auto curr = head;
    while(curr != nullptr) {
        auto resultPair = table.insert(curr);
        if(!resultPair.second) {  // found duplicate
            return curr;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>* getLastNode(Node<T>* head)
{
    auto curr = head;
    while(curr->next != nullptr) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return curr;
}

int main()
{
    auto nonLooped = makeLinkedList("ABCDE");

    auto looped = makeLinkedList("ABCDE");
    auto last = getLastNode(looped);
    auto cNode = looped->next->next;
    last->next = cNode;

    assert(findBeginning(nonLooped) == nullptr);
    assert(findBeginning(looped)->val == 'C');
}
```

Now I wonder if findBeginning is a good Solution for the problem? I think it is very easy to understand. The reason I ask this is because the book only presents an other solution which does not need an additional data structure but uses to pointers to race each other.

**BookSolution (Translated by me from Java to C++):**

```
template<typename T>
Node<T>* findBeginning(Node<T>* head)
{
    auto slow = head;
    auto fast = heas;

    // Find meeting point. This will be LOOP_SIZE -k steps into the linked list
    while (fast != nullptr && fast->next != nullptr) {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
        if (slow = fast) { // Collision
            break;
        }
    }

    // Error Check - no meeting point, and therefore no loop
    if (fast == nullptr || fast->next == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    // Move slow to Head. Keep fast at Meeting Point. Each are k steps from the
    // Loop Start. If they move at the same pace, they must meet at Loop start
    slow = head;
    while (slow != fast) {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
    }

    // Both now point to the start of the loop
    return fast;
}
```

Let me know what you think about both solutions. Is there another Solution you would solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common interview question.

There are two common solutions.

1. Walk the list and see if you find a common node.
2. Walk the list with two pointers. One pointer goes at speed 1 the second pointer moves at speed 2. If there is a loop they will eventually match or you will reach the end of the list.

The problem with technique 1 is that it can use up a large amount of memory storing all the nodes you have found. The problem with the second technique is that it does not find the node where the loop happens (it just detects the loop) but does not use up any extra space.

So you have picked a good solution to the problem (as stated) as you need to find the node where loop is formed.

The only comment of the test is that this is not required.

```
if(head == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Since you don't give much to review I will also look at the code creating the list. Again not much to review here:

But we can simplify the makeLinkedList().

```
Node<char>* makeLinkedList(const std::string& values)
{
    Node<char>  sentinal('?', nullptr);
    Node<char>* curr = &sentinal;

    for(const auto& val: values) {
       curr->next = new Node<char>{val, nullptr};
       curr = curr->next;
    }
    return sentinal->next;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to optimize for ease of understanding, then your solution is indeed better than the book solution. However, in general the best algorithms are those that are fast and use little memory. The book solution is hard to beat.

If this is a programming challenge, and you don't care what happens with the linked list afterwards, then another possible solution is to modify nodes in some way to record whether you have visited them or not. For example, you can assume that pointers are aligned to at least 4 bytes, and thus store data in the lowest two bits without destroying any information. Thus you could solve the problem like so:

```
template<typename T>
Node<T>* findBeginning(Node<T>* head)
{
    while (head) {
        if ((uintptr_t)head->next & 1) {
            break;
        }

        auto next = head->next;
        head->next = (Node<T> *)((uintptr_t)head->next | 1);
        head = next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: At least de-mangle the pointers you have messed with before returning.

Comment: @MartinYork I did mention this solution is only for programming challenges where you don't care about the linked list afterwards. Otherwise, I would just go for Floyd's cycle finding algorithm.

Comment: @MartinYork Considering that OP's code (and both answers to date) assume leaking is fine, what does a little more breakage matter.